# No Taxonomist Badge?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, taxonomist-badge

The 50<sup>th</sup> question on Stack Overflow tagged with the [go](/questions/tagged/go) tag has been asked; as far as I know [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712172/whats-your-take-on-the-programming-language-go) was the first with the tag, yet I have not received the Taxonomist badge. What am I missing?

Comment: Oh, so *you're* the one to blame for all that nonsense. =P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sorry, UserId for the [go] tag is null.

Creation date was **2008**-11-07 14:31:52.

So it was already co-opted by another user who was probably long since culled due to inactivity.

I am also guessing it was attached to a question for a long long time until the retagging around the new language happened.

Comment: It was probably created by someone referencing the *game* Go.

Comment: Something about that doesn't seem right, especially if the tagging was later found to be inappropriate for the question.

Comment: the underlying problem here is silly names being given to programming languages.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely awarded in a batch process. I'm sure you'll get it soon.