# Unexpected Taxonomist badge

Tags: support, badges

I just [got the Taxonomist badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=1033808) for the [[pinterest]](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pinterest) tag. However, I am quite sure I did not create that tag. I can think of a few things that could have happened:

- The mention of the pinterest tag is false, and I got the badge for a different tag.
- There was a glitch in the system.
- I created the badge and do not recall creating it....

What to do in such a situation?

Comment: I like your honesty.

Comment: Well, you added the tag to the oldest question with that tag. I assume that counts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The revision history.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9035291/revisions)

The oldest question with this tag was created January 27, and you edited the tag onto that question the same day. *Every other* question with this tag was created after that, so it's not possible that the tag existed prior to that tag edit.

Apparently you did create it and just don't recall doing so.

Comment: I think it was during my reviewing spree when I wanted to get my editing badges :).

Comment: It's perfectly possible for the tag to have been created before that, if the question(s) with it were untagged or deleted, but this is the most likely explanation.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra: Is it possible that this tag already existed on an older question which was deleted in the mean time? That would account for that fact that you don't remember creating it - maybe you really didn't.

Comment: I am quite active in some tags, but none are even remotely related to pinterest. But after seeing the revision history I remember adding the tag when I was reviewing using the 'review' button above next to my name.

Comment: @animuson, thanks for the fast response and pointing to the revison history, +1!

Comment: @MatthewRead: I don't believe the system would be so naive that it would forget who actually created the tag just because that question was untagged or deleted. Of course, one could argue that if the question got untagged or deleted, then they didn't really "create" it since it (the tag *or* the question) didn't belong there.

Comment: @animuson If the tag is deleted after the first time it's created then [nobody will get credit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29759/no-taxonomist-badge).

Comment: @animuson I didn't say anything about forgetting, I just sad that `it's not possible that the tag existed prior to that tag edit` is not a valid conclusion to draw from `Every other question with this tag was created after that`.  I agree that the system is not naive about this, in fact I know it isn't unless something broke or was buggy :P