# Why do some tag info pages show who created them and others don't?

Tags: support, tags

Some [tag info pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/winter-bash-2017/info) show who created the tag:

[image]

while [others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/winter-bash-2018/info) don't. I'm pretty sure I created that one as well, if you hover over the timestamp you can see when it was created:

[image]

which more or less matches with [this edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/305500/revisions#spacer-54709d28-e36b-4158-8543-1f745e00560b) where I created the tag:

[image]

I understand that some tags like [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) were probably created by the Community user while the site itself was created (so it [doesn't show an author](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/discussion/info)), but some newer tags like [winter-bash](/questions/tagged/winter-bash) [don't show an author either](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/winter-bash/info) even though [the creator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/214423/revisions#spacer-9ee3d83e-339e-4f39-9d1e-e5dca8e4dc1c) still has an account here.

What's going on here? Would this also mean I wouldn't get a [Taxonomist badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist) for [winter-bash-2018](/questions/tagged/winter-bash-2018) if I [didn't already have one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=295232)?

Comment: Also asked on MSO: [What tags are created by nobody?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287783/4642212).

Comment: Tags created and then removed and deleted, then reapplied, don't attach to the subsequent creators and show blank credit. Source: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132170/unexpected-taxonomist-badge#comment365407_132174 (and follow the link).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is no Taxonomist badge for a tag, its creator won't show in the tag info page.

This was said indirectly by Jarrod in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247148/152859):

> If a tag has a related Taxonomist badge, the creator will now be shown on its tag wiki/info page

So from this we can conclude that if a badge does *not* have related Taxonomist badge, its creator won't show in the tag info page.

Comment: Thanks. That's a rather half-baked implementation then...

Comment: @Glorfindel not sure about the reasoning behind it, surely there is something at play e.g. faster development time for doing it this way. :)