# Remove the badge-activated tag creator, or just always show the creator

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-experience

As explained on [Why do some tag info pages show who created them and others don't?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318296/392799) tags where the *Taxonomist* badge was awarded show the creator, while the rest don't. This was introduced by [Show a tag's creator on the tag wiki page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108239/392799).

> [image: Stats of the [head-of-state-transport] tag, not showing the username of its creator]
> Link: [head-of-state-transport/info](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tags/head-of-state-transport/info)

> [image: Stats of the [thrust] tag, showing the username of its creator]
> Link: [thrust/info](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tags/thrust/info)

This has no value, and only causes confusion (see question's history and first linked question).

All or none would be better.

Comment: To be honest, I think the created by part should just be removed. It's one of those "fun to know" things that adds no value whatsoever to those stats because who created a tag should not matter to anyone. I'm not sure why that request from so long ago was even completed... It's also weird to show a date relevant to when the *tag* was created right next to two stats that have nothing to do with the tag, but the wiki you are viewing. Just bad UI.

Comment: I think the reason this is only shown on the Taxonomist badge being awarded is because there was a [concern](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/6822/377214) raised a while ago that showing it for all tags would result in people gaming the badge by applying a tag they created to a bunch of random questions. Restricting the display to cases where it was already awarded would mitigate that issue.

Comment: Similar duplicate, old and claiming status-completed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108239/282094

Comment: Hi @Rob: That post is where *the current issue* was introduced.

Comment: ymb1, yes, the *claim* of fulfilling the question falls short of "just always show the creator"; and even further from "Remove the badge-activated tag creator" asked for **here** ***and*** never met "Show a tag's creator on the tag wiki page" originally asked for. In any event it's not a dupe to re-ask so many years later, especially after multiple UI changes, and the info is useful in some instances when you want to ask the creator what was the intended usage (where they sinned, not creating at least the excerpt) and there some Wiki writing or retagging to be done.

Comment: @Rob Presumably if it's not clear how the tag is being used, then it's only being used on a couple questions and one could just ask the editors that added the tag in the comments on those questions. We don't allow direct messaging users, so I don't know how else you'd go ask the creator what they meant. [Some creators don't even remember doing so.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132170/unexpected-taxonomist-badge)

Comment: I wonder how often moderators find it useful when trying to hunt down who created a horrible tag so they can ask them to exercise more caution. That's the only scenario (finding out who created a bad tag) I can think of where it is even mildly useful.